# How do I make my calculator accept multiple values and multiple operators before pressing the equal button?

Tags: vb.net, math, operators

I'm a newbie in VB.NET so I followed a tutorial. The current code only takes the first value, operator, and then the second value before I press the equal button. It's working as intended. But I want to know how to make it accept multiple values and multiple operators before I press the Equal button.

Here is the current code  for the operator buttons and the equal button and the variables declared:

```
Dim firstval, secondval, result As Double
Dim op As String

Private Sub Operator_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button17.Click, Button16.Click, Button15.Click, Button14.Click
    Dim b As Button = sender

    firstval = Label1.Text
    Label2.Text = Label1.Text
    Label1.Text = ""
    op = b.Text
    Label2.Text = Label2.Text + " " + op

End Sub

Private Sub Button13_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click
    secondval = Label1.Text


    If op = "+" Then
        result = firstval + secondval
        Label1.Text = result


    ElseIf op = "-" Then
        result = firstval - secondval
        Label1.Text = result


    ElseIf op = "×" Then
        result = firstval * secondval
        Label1.Text = result

    ElseIf op = "÷" Then
        result = firstval / secondval
        Label1.Text = result
        If secondval = "0" Then
            Label1.Text = ""
            Label3.Text = "CANNOT DIVIDE BY ZERO"
        End If


    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You're using VB.NET, not VBA

Comment: RPN https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm  -  Other algorithm in 'See also'.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a string to store the entire math problem the user inputs and add the number or operator to it depending on the button you click. This way you could have practically infinite amounts operators and numbers.

When the string is done you can let it calculate when the "=" button or whatever button you're using is pressed.

You would start by declaring the variable

```
Dim input As String
```

Then use this code when you click a button

```
input = input + NAMEOFBUTTON.text
```

This will make it add the content of the button to the current input. NAMEOFBUTTON would be the name of the button the code runs under.
You might need to use "/" as the button name for division.

When clicking on "=" this code should run:

```
Dim output = New DataTable().Compute(input, Nothing)
```

Then you could use a label to display the output. NAMEOFLABEL is of course the name of the label you display it on.
You might need to convert the output to a string before showing it on a label.

```
NAMEOFLABEL.text = output.ToString
```